# Design to read 100K records from a flat file and process them to DB in Java

Tags: java, spring, caching, design-patterns

I am designing an API in Java with Spring Framework that will read a flat file containing 100K records and compare them with values fetched from database. If the DB values are available in the file values then they will be updated in the database.

The concern in the entire process is performance. 
I have a maximum of 7 minutes to perform the entire processing of 100K records.

I am looking to use a caching mechanism to fetch all the data from the database in a cache bean. The cache will be refreshed every 30 mins or 1 hour.
Second, we will read the file and compare the values with the values in the cache and the matched values will be stored in another cache.
Third, we will update the values from the second cache to the database using a threading mechanism.

I need some opinions on this design. Does it look good.
Any advice to improve the design is welcome.

P.S. : Database in use is DB2 hosted on Mainframe systems

Thanks
Nirmalya

Comment: Leave the data in the database. (If you look for a caching mechanism to cache already fetched data, take a look at ehcache.) Read about 500 lines from the file (depends on the size of such a line) and store it to the database with a batch update query. Repeat that until there are no more lines to read.

Comment: @Nirmalya Does DB2 has BULK insert capabilities? With MSSQL you can define a file format and let SQL import records directly from a file. If you could do that then it's just a matter of updating everything with the new information. It shouldn't take very long for 100k records.

Comment: @Stefan I cannot go with that as I am not going to store all the records from the file in the DB. I will update only those records which matches - the DB value and the value from the file. If such a match happens, only then I would update (not insert) the record already in the DB, like updating a column with the new value from the file

Comment: You can use "having" to check for matches.

Comment: @plalx That is something I am also wondering, if we have any bulk update capabilities in DB2,it would be easier to do that. What I was looking at an efficient way to match the values from the file with the values from the DB.

Comment: @Stefan I cannot do that in a stored procedure. As I said I will be getting 100K  records. Performing a having clause will be very time consuming. I would do the comparing in the java level and send the bulk records to DB for bulk updated. So you have any idea if DB2 supports Bulk Update? If so how do you write the algorithm for it?